# IntelliJ-IDEA Persistence-Tab in Spring-Boot applications

Tags: jpa, intellij-idea, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a problem configuring the perstistance tab within a spring boot application (with spring-data-jpa) so that I can use the jql console.

after setting up the jpa-facete, the provider (hibernate) and assigning the datasource (postgres), I'm able to browse my entities and have correct autocompletion in my jql-query annotations / entity pojos in my code and so on.

The only thing that is not working correctly is the jql console. For tables with simple column names (no underline / camelcase) it works, but for column names that contain underlines it seems intellij uses the wrong naming-startegy (non camelcase) while my spring boot application uses another one with camel case by default.

I am aware of the fact that spring boot does all that jpa magic programatically while intellij supports a presistence.xml file which would normally be used by the application to configure the jpa-layer. So I tried to set up such a file only for the presistance tab to work correctly - with no success.

But actually I hope that this file isn't needed at all since everything but the naming strategy works out of the box.

any help or hint in the right direction is very much appreciated.